# How to get git hub push events using curl

Tags: python, github, github-api

I need to fetch all push events in my remote repo for my organization with curl or git api.
I cannot use the web hook feature in GitHub because my webhook server is running behind a firewall.So github.com cannot call my  webhook url.i need to get the webhook payload using curl

when i try:-

```
curl -X GET -u $GITHUB_USER:$GITHUB_PASSWORD https://api.github.com/repos/:org/:repo/events
```

getting all events like push and create,i only need push events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the output of that curl command to `jq` and pick out just the events with type `PushEvent`, like this:

```sh
curl \
    -X GET \
    -u $GITHUB_USER:$GITHUB_PASSWORD \
    https://api.github.com/repos/:org/:repo/events \
  | jq '.[] | select(.type == "PushEvent")'
```

Note that the second `|` pipe is inside `''` single-quotes as it part of the arguments to `jq`. It is not for the shell.

Comment: how can i do the same with python json

Comment: Python doesn't support JSON as a native data type, so you would need to `import json` and then use that library (probably `json.load()` or `json.loads()`) to convert it into a Python `dict`.  As far as how you would get the data in the first place, instead of using `curl` you could `import requests` and then use that library to build an `HTTP GET` request for the target URL, using the same authentication credentials. If you do that, and if the URL returns valid JSON, then the response object return by the requests library will have a `json()` method that will convert to `dict` for you.

Comment: If that is difficult to follow, you can open a new question to ask about the Python version. It's easier to give a clear answer that way.